# is it possible to give a default value to a variable in a snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Consider you are creating 2 variables namely, Industry and IsPrivate; and you do not want to give a value for IsPrivate variable and if you don't, it should automatically take NULL as its value. So, what steps should I take to make the following query correct?
set (Industry, IsPrivate) = ('Technology');

Comment: In what context are you doing this?

Comment: I have a table that has several columns including Industry and IsPrivate and IsPrivate column has some null values, and I want to select data by giving value to these variables. When set(Industry, IsPrivate) = ('Technology','Yes'), it should show data that has Technology as Industry and Yes as IsPrivate. But when I don't give value for 2nd variable like this set (Industry, IsPrivate) = ('Technology'), it should give all the data which has Technology as Industry and null as IsPrivate, so is it possible? Is there something I can add before setting these variables, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

if you have your table defined like

```
CREATE TABLE table (industry text, isprivate boolean);
```

then insert values with

```
INSERT INTO table (industry) VALUES ('Technology');
```

is valid

your use of the word `SET` make it seem like you are doing an `UPDATE`, with the above table

```
UPDATE table SET industry = 'Technology';
```

is 100% valid.

If you have the above table and you want to change the default after having inserted data then:

```
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN isprivate  SET DEFUALT FALSE;
```

is invalid. You ether need to rebuild the table,

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (industry text, isprivate boolean default false);
INSERT INTO table2 AS
    SELECT industry
        ,COALESCE(isprivate , FALSE) AS isprivate
    FROM table;
ALTER TABLE table2  SWAP WITH table;
DROP TABLE table2; -- now the old one.
```

or just default on read via COALESCE.

```
SELECT industry, COALESCE(isprivate , FALSE) AS isprivate
FROM table;
```